# How to write to a new File object

Tags: java

I created a new file like this:

```
File f = new File(filename);
if (!f.exists()) {
    f.createNewFile();
}
```

how do I write to it? I only found how to write to a Path object using `Files.write`

Comment: By creating a [`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) or a [`FileWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [BufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) like this

```
File f = new File(filename);
BufferedWriter bw = null;
try
{
   bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
   bw.write("some data");
} catch (IOException ex)
{
    //do something 
} finally
{
    if (bw != null)
    {
        try
        {
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

With modern Java (7+), this can be condensed as:

```
File f = new File(filename);
try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f)))
{
   bw.write("some data");
} catch (IOException ex)
{
    //do something 
}
```

with the use of [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)